# Can we eliminate the login step from default checkout and force to use the default login page?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, login

I wanted to remove the login step from Magento's default checkout and making users to be redirected to the default login page, it doesn't make sense having 2 logins forms.

Is that possible? Important: after logging in, user needs to be redirected to checkout after that instead of account page or whatever page else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something you can achieve with default Magento. You could make this work with just a simple observer for the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index`. In that observer, you could do a check if the user is checked in or not. If not, you can redirect the user to the account/login page.

You will need a custom module for this. This code should get you on the right track:

**app/modules/Namespace_CheckoutLoggedin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_CheckoutLoggedin>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_CheckoutLoggedin>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Namespace/CheckoutLoggedin/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_CheckoutLoggedin>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_CheckoutLoggedin>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <namespace_checkoutloggedin>
                <class>Namespace_CheckoutLoggedin_Model</class>
            </namespace_checkoutloggedin>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
                <observers>
                    <checkout_customer_loggedin>
                        <class>namespace_checkoutloggedin/observer</class>
                        <method>checkCustomerLoggedin</method>
                    </checkout_customer_loggedin>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Namespace/CheckoutLoggedin/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Namespace_CheckoutLoggedin_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkCustomerLoggedin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
        }
    }
}
```

The code is untested, so maybe it doesn't work out-of-the-box, but this should give you an idea on how to fix this.

Comment: It worked man! Sorry, I'm just the front guy. As I have no knowledge with mvc architecture, I don't know how to do those stuff yet. Firstly, your code on Observer.php had generated this error: "ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Custom_CheckoutLoggedin_Model_Observer::checkCustomerLoggedin() must be an instance of Varien_Observer, instance of Varien_Event_Observer". After I removed this "Varien_Observer $observer", Magento hasn't log an error anymore.

Comment: Glad I could help. Changed it in my answer

Answer (score 2):

I already found out what I was looking for, just added the following php code on "onepage.phtml":

```
if (!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
    // Add a message that will display on the login page
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Please log in or create an account to checkout.');

    // Create the redirection
    header("Location: " . $this->helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
    exit();
}
```

It worked like a charm, so that way allow us to skip unnecessary work to customize and have 2 logins. Hope this helps everyone!

Answer (score 0):

System menu>Configuration>Checkout button in the Sales section on the left>Checkout Options panel on the right. After you expand the Checkout Options panel you'll see a drop-down menu Allow Guest Checkout; just set it to No.

Try this.Hope this will work.

Comment: That option is already set to "No" and it only makes difference by allowing users to register themselves on the checkout page, I mean, the button "Register" takes the user to the default register page as expected, but that is not happening with login. Instead Magento showing the one page checkout with a form, the user should be taken to the "/customer/account/login" page and use the login form in that page and not on checkout. I'm not sure if a redirect would work correctly, so I would like to hear from you if there is some valid and safe option, without "compromise" Magento functionality.