# How can I redirect user to log in page for checkout instead of using the login modal?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, login

Currently, we have guest checkout disabled on our store. When someone tries to go to checkout, a modal appears asking them to log in or create an account.

Is there a way to disable this in Magento 2, or do we need to do the equivalent of [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168054/can-we-eliminate-the-login-step-from-default-checkout-and-force-to-use-the-defau) and use a custom module?

Comment: You need to develope custom module which check customer login or not and then perform things according your requirement.